# Android - Contextual ActionBar with ListFragments inside ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, fragment, contextual-action-bar

Good evening!

Question: What is the best method of invoking the Contextual ActionBar when long selecting a row inside of a ListFragment?

My Situation: I have a ViewPager backed by a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, this ViewPager contains 9 different instances of the same ListFragment. Should I be invoking the CAB from the Activity? Or should this be done inside the fragment?

Thank you.

Comment: you should invoke it from fragment because CAB is tied with the listview itself

Comment: Perfect, That is what I did. Works well. Just wanted to make sure this was the appropriate route.